# Flying from Amsterdam to Zurich - do I need a passport?

Tags: schengen, passports, amsterdam

I just arrived in Amsterdam (by train) and realized I left my passport home in Switzerland. I am a US citizen residing in Switzerland, and I have my Swiss resident permit with me. I have a flight back to Zurich in a few days, and I'm wondering if I'll have any trouble with passport checks when flying. In theory because both countries are part of Schengen and I have a residence permit in a Schengen country, it should be fine, but I'm wondering if anyone has firsthand experience about this situation. Is there any real risk?

Comment: Which airline are you flying? Although there are no passport checks within Schengen, the Terms and Conditions of some low-cost carriers (for example EasyJet) require travel documents for all passengers (mainly to prevent unauthorized resale of tickets).

Comment: There is no official check, but from time to time there are checks. You should always have with you some official document (maybe not so large [for a pocket] as a passport). As @TooTea: some airlines (but not only the cheap one, Swiss will do it regularly) will check that a ID will match ticket name before boarding.

Comment: I've never had my ID asked at the gate for a SWISS flight (and I fly with them about 40 times a year) at any European airport. They do ask for an ID when dropping of luggage though. There will not be any border control. 
Which type of resident permit do you have? The folded paper in a plastic cover type, or the new credit card format type? I would expect the credit card format one to be more readily accepted as an ID by a gate agent.

Comment: @KristvanBesien The booklet-type residence permit is only issued to asylees and EU/Schengen citizens

Comment: @Crazydre explains why that is what I had (before I was naturalised...)

Comment: @KristvanBesien It's what I have as well, though it only leaves my drawer when going to the *Einwohneramt* to extend it

Comment: WIll be flying EasyJet. And my REsidence permit is the plastic card variety. Am already checked in online and have boarding pass on my phone. No need to check a bag, so It's just getting through the security and at the gate.

The amsterdam website basically says there won't be passport check to get through if going to another schengen country, but that you should have some identuty card. This makes me think my residence permit card will be sufficient.

Comment: @PaulZander With easyJet it won't be enough. You need the passport

Comment: This is much delayed, but in case anyone is in a similar situation, my experience was that there was no passport check when flying from Amsterdam to Zurich on Easyjet (no checked bag)